# Recover Radi1 setup after bad Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: partitioning, raid

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 and destroyed my life - lol.

I had a working machine with 3 partitions on sda: / /home and swap. I had these mirrored to sdb.

After the failed upgrade I tried everything possible to recover but only one solution worked with an old LiveCD meaning I was eventually (through a sequence of version upgrades) able to get to a new / (Ubuntu 19.04) on sda1 with a new /home now also on sda1.  So now I also have my old /home on sda3 with all my data on it and mirrored to sdb3.  What I now want to do (before remounting my old /home over the new one which I have seen how to do) is to get sdb1 (which has Ubuntu 18.04 on it) to be a Raid1 mirror of the new sda1 (Ubuntu 19.04 on it); the problem I have is that the new sda1 does not appear to have a superblock now?

I get the message "no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1" when I use the command "sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1"

Thanks in advance

Comment: While it might be convenient to blame Ubuntu, looks like you had an entire sequence of failures: No backups, booting from RAID, a complex system, and some kind of vague upgrade problem. You can learn from this awful experience to make your system more resilient and more easily recoverable.

Comment: I would suggest you just retrieve your data, place it onto an external drive, networked drive or storage somewhere, then re-build your system as you want it & restore your data.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two supported & tested upgrade paths, firstly to 18.10 (ie. off the LTS upgrade path and not skipping any releases), or secondly to 20.04 direct (LTS to next LTS, but after 20.04.1's release so late 2020 as testing here hasn't really started there yet) so you were trying to do an **untested & unsupported** release-upgrade anyway

Comment: Will do, just wondered if there was a way I could get around the super-block issue but I guess not.  FYI, the reason I couldn't recover was that after the upgrade something really crazy happened where whenever I dropped into any of the recovery options in the grub menu I couldn't see any text, just the pinky-purple and grey colours.  I assume it was some kind of graphics-card config issue but have never seen it happen before and couldn't find any help on it.  Anyway that's over now, will back up and re-install.  Thanks!